# meaning of underscrore '_' in python

Tags: python

```
# Step 1: Download the data.
url = 'http://mattmahoney.net/dc/'


def maybe_download(filename, expected_bytes):
  """Download a file if not present, and make sure it's the right size."""
  if not os.path.exists(filename):
    filename, _ = urllib.request.urlretrieve(url + filename, filename)
  statinfo = os.stat(filename)
```

In the above, what does `filename, _` refer to? The second underscore especially.

Answer (score 2):

It’s a convention for an ignored value. `_` is a valid variable name like any other, but the writer’s intent is to say “I’m unpacking a two-value tuple and only using the first value”.